# Вытащить версию конфигурации внешней обработкой

Tags: 1с

Пишу внешнюю обработку для автоматизации формирования комплекта поставок. Было предложено сделать выгрузку конфигурации в файлы, а там найти `Configuration.xml` и в нём нашарить `<version>`. Проблема в том, что нужен только корень конфигурации, а не всё подряд, не то время на выгрузку всю необходимость автоматизации и убьёт.
Пробую через `/DumpConfigToFiles <имя каталога> -listFile <имя файла>` вытащить.

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура СоздатьКомплект(Команда)
//..
    Текст_ = Новый ЗаписьТекста(
    ЭтотОбъект.КаталогВременныхФайлов + "\list.txt",
    КодировкаТекста.UTF8,
    Символы.ПС,
    Ложь
);
Текст_.Записать("Configuration");
Текст_.Закрыть();
//..
```

И сама выгрузка

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ВытащитьТекущуюВерсиюКонфигурации()
СтрокаКоманды_ = СтрШаблон(
    """%1"" config /F ""%2"" /N ""%3"" /P ""%4"" /DumpConfigToFiles ""%5"" -listFile ""%6"" /Out 1cv8.log",
    ЭтотОбъект.ПутьКbin + "\1cv8.exe",
    ЭтотОбъект.ПутьККонфигурации,
    ЭтотОбъект.login,
    ЭтотОбъект.password,
    ЭтотОбъект.КаталогВременныхФайлов,
    ЭтотОбъект.КаталогВременныхФайлов + "\list.txt"
);
    ЗапуститьПриложение(СтрокаКоманды_, ЭтотОбъект.КаталогВременныхФайлов, Истина, 0);
КонецПроцедуры
```

В итоге в выкинутом `1cv8.log` такой текст:

> Ошибка в файле списка выгружаемых объектов: Configuration не является именем объекта метаданных или свойства.

По всякому уже пробовал список файлов заполнять - `Configuration`, `Configuration.xml`... - всё не то.
Что мне в TXTшник пихнуть, чтобы только корень выгрузить? Ну или хотя бы сделать выгрузку корня вместе с каким-то мусором, но чтоб он не сильно на время работы повлиял(а конфигурация очень большая).

UPD: Хранилище конфигурации висит на линуховом сервере.

UPD: Нашёл такое `Конфигурация -> Отчет по конфигурации`. Там версия есть. Тогда вопрос: можно ли программно отчёты вшитые в конфигурацию выгрузить в файл?

Comment: Приветствую. А нельзя просто выполнить код: Метаданные.Версия
?

Comment: Нет, Метаданные недоступны для чтения из внешней обработки.

Comment: Для получения отчетов по хранилищу используется ключ /ConfigurationRepositoryReport.

Примеры:
для конфигурации, не присоединенной к текущему хранилищу:

DESIGNER /F"D:\V8\Cfgs82\ИБ82" /ConfigurationRepositoryF "D:\V8\Cfgs82" /ConfigurationRepositoryN "Администратор" /ConfigurationRepositoryReport "D:\ByObject.mxl" -NBegin 1 -NEnd 2 –GroupByObject

для присоединенной к хранилищу конфигурации, информация для отчетов берется из текущего хранилища:

DESIGNER /F"D:\V8\Cfgs82\ИБ82" /ConfigurationRepositoryReport "D:\ByComment.mxl" -NBegin 1 -NEnd 2 -GroupByComment

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, цепляться по COM-соединению к этой конфигурации и через метаданные получать версию.

ОбъектМетаданныхКонфигурация.Версия (ConfigurationMetadataObject.Version)
ОбъектМетаданныхКонфигурация (ConfigurationMetadataObject)
Версия (Version)
Использование:

Только чтение. 
Описание:

Тип: Строка. 
Версия конфигурации.

Comment: За ответ сойдёт, спасибо. Но хранилище конфигурации на линуховом сервере, COMОбъекты не пройдут)

Comment: Кстати, а если запускать в пользовательском режиме с параметром /Execute путь_к_внешней_обработке, в которой как раз будет выполняться получение версии конфигурации (Метаданные.Версия) и сохраняться в необходимый каталог?